# Random de 1 a 500 sem repetir

Tags: php, javascript, random

Tenho uma tabela no banco de dados com ids de 1 a 500, a cada vez que a página é atualizada **um numero** sorteado aparece e eu faço um select e exibo uma mensagem que está no id selecionado, porém gostaria que a cada atualizada os números não se repetissem até chegar no ultimo e assim zerar e recomeçar novamente.

Conseguiria fazer isso apenas com o javascript? ou terei que usar php?

Comment: Conseegue, pesquise por "Fisher-yates" aqui mesmo no site para saber o algoritmo. Basicamente você armazena um array no browser (cookies, localstorage etc). Se fizer do lado do PHP, com session ou mecanismo similar é melhor. Basta "embaralhar" os numeros eem um array, e refazer o sorteio só depois de usar todos (não precisa mexer no DB pra isso). Seria importante você [edit] seu post e colocar o código que está usando como base, a estrutura do DB ou array usado, etc, para servir como base para as respostas. - Do lado do PHP ja tem função pronta http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shuffle.php

Comment: @Bacco vi um poste seu a respeito mais achei complicado rsrsrs pois no meu caso eu só quero um resultado por vez e de alguma forma eu acredito q algum momento a função pode ficar lenta devido ao numero de registros, vo depois da uma analisada com mais calma, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: 500 numeros é um valor baixissimo. Basta vc fazer um array e $sorteado = shuffle( $original ). Ai vai tirando um por um do array até acabar (e só sorteia de novo quando acabar o array). Se bobear com umas 8 linhas de código faz o processo todo. Lembrando que basta sortear os numeros, o resto pega do DB conforme o numero atual só na hora de usar - if (count($sorteado)==0) { gera e embaralha }; retira o 1o do array e usa. Guarda de volta na sessão; - basicamente isso resolve tudo

Comment: entendi, mas a tendencia é esse numero crescer, de qualquer forma deu para eu entender a sua logica e farei uns testes aqui tb, obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode adicionar a essa tabela a coluna `TINY INT (1)`, de por exemplo de nome `usado` e na hora da busca fazer a busca limitado a um com a condição usado `0` ,

Por exemplo:

```
SELECT column 
FROM table
WHERE usado = 0
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

nessa query eu pego um registro aleatório limitado a um que ainda não tenha sido usado,

Após pegar esse registro você atualiza o mesmo para `usado = 1`

Por exemplo:

```
UPDATE table SET usado=1 WHERE id=aqui_seria_o_id_recebido_na_busca_anterior
```

Quando rodar a primeira query deixe uma condição para caso a busca não retorne nada, ele rode um update para atualizar a toda a tabela e assim rodar o `select` novamente.

Exemplo:

```
UPDATE table SET usado=0
```

No caso eu simplesmente estou atualizando toda a tabela para o status `usado = 0`.

Todas essas alterações ficariam no lado do servidor, sendo assim não precisaria alterar html nem `javascript`, mas claro essa é apenas umas ideia minha. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: entendi, eu havia pensando na possibilidade do update mais sem o rand, já é um caminho apesar deu preferir uma forma que não dependesse do update, de qualquer forma já é uma solução, obrigado ;)

Comment: uma outra dúvida @Bulfaitelo, ao final quando se acabasse as opções, como eu poderia resetar todos os registros para 0 de uma só vez? qual a melhor opção? obrigado.

Comment: @PatriqueAlves Necessariamente você precisa de alguma forma de saber quais já foram usados, por isso o update, com relação a segunda pergunta eu vou editar e colocar essa atualização.

Comment: super entendido, deu pra clarear bastante aqui e já fiz o teste, ajudou bastante, obrigado!